# How to send the url of the page the form is located

Tags: solspace-freeform

Using the freeform field type to display the form. Is it possible to send the url of the page the form is located.

I've tried using a hidden form and prepopulating with {segment_data}.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Freeform and EE are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I normally do something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="my_form_field_name" value="{site_url}/{if segment_1}{segment_1}/{/if}{if segment_2}{segment_2}/{/if}">
```